# How to render single frame instead of repeating frames?

Tags: rendering, image

I have an animation that has three(3) still images in it. Each image stays for 3 seconds and then switch to next image. I don't want to render same image for 3 seconds(That is 180 frames) but in animation video that same frame should stay for 3 seconds.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just render your three images into picture files, then import them into your favorite video editing software and make them last any time you'd like.